# Starting a new thread in service for a responsive UI

Tags: android

I would like to take advice of the community on the approach I have followed. Is this a good approach or there is something better way..

As my service(which runs periodically) is local to my app, my assumption is that service runs in the main thread itself. So if service and activity are running the activity becomes less responsive.
My assumption is that starting a new thread will ease of main thread and UI will be more responsive..

onStartCommand
start a thread
let the newly created thread post a message (delayed) to itself via postDelayed and provide serviceRunnable in which main service work is done. In the same runnable the postDelayed is called again.

Please let me know if this theory is correct

Answer (score 0):

UI can only be run on the main thread, but you can run a Service on another background thread see the instructions below
https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/index.html

Comment: postDelayed or starting new IntentService which would consume less cpu

Comment: I would use the lowest cpu consuming method. My service has to comeup every 30 secs and insert something in a DB which UI would read.